# Can I install canonical-livepatch on a system without snapd

Tags: snap, canonical-livepatch

On my ubuntu server, I won't install `snapd`. But without snapd, I cannot install `canonical-livepatch`. Is there a potentially inofficial version of livepatch as traditional `.deb` file, for install using `dpkg` or `apt-get`, or a conversion script which can create such a .deb file from the given snap?

Comment: Canonical wants to migrate from traditional packages to snaps (gives sandboxes).  Any particular reason you won't install snapd?

Comment: Mainly security concerns. And the fact that all these snap layers are hard to control. snap is the wrong technology. If I want a modular system I use ranger os. my opinion,..

Comment: And also: ubuntu started as a debian derivate, and the main point of debian is its stable and lightweight package management. there is absolutely no reason to replace the core technology behind a distribution by something which is not even stable yet

Comment: @alder then switch to Debian.

Comment: this doesn't bring me live-patch

Comment: Then just use ubuntu like they want you to. Much less pain down that path

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen From your first message you were off topic and you are still. Keep your comments for yourself as long you can't answer the question

Comment: First of all, asking _why_ you want to do something which is clearly not how Canonical intend it to be used (explained with "I won't") is not off-topic, that is getting valuable information (for instance is this an X-Y problem?).  Secondly saying that you should use it the way Canonical intend it to be used (because doing so will give you fewer problems down the line in my experience) _is_ answering the question, just not an answer you like to hear.

Comment: No. it is _an_ answer which doesn't fit the requirements and btw between the lines I already showed that I know this possible answer, so there isn't even any new information.  It's nothing wrong with asking for my motivation. but there's something wrong with not accepting the provided answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

No. Canonical Livepatch is only (currently) distributed as a snap. You could find some other way to unpack the snap and install the binaries manually, but I doubt you'd get support for that from Canonical.

Comment: support is secondary. I can't expect much as a non-paying individual anyway

Comment: The snap doesn't contain a lot, and can easily be unpacked with `unsquashfs`, but I don't know if it works when re-packed. Something to play with I guess.